# Find duplicate values in excel worksheet using conditional formatting programmatically

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, conditional-statements

i need to find duplicate values in excel worksheet using conditional formating programmatically.

Tried this way, but in 6 line of code i've got COM exception

> cannot cast to Excel.FormatCondition

Here's my code

```
Excel.Workbook xlWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWS = xlWB.ActiveSheet;
xlWS.Range["B2:B9"].Select();
Excel.Range xlS = Application.Selection;
xlS.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues();
Excel.FormatCondition xlFC = 
    (Excel.FormatCondition)xlS.FormatConditions[xlS.FormatConditions.Count];
xlFC.SetFirstPriority();
Excel.FormatCondition xlFC1 = (Excel.FormatCondition)xlS.FormatConditions[1];
xlFC1.Interior.Pattern = Excel.XlPattern.xlPatternAutomatic;
xlFC1.Interior.TintAndShade = 0;
xlFC1.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.FromOle(13551615);
```

Comment: how would you go about doing this in excel manually?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at it [MSDN Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/995f883c-bd4c-4f9a-b4cd-099320d5c721)

or you could possibly use something like this

```
 Excel.Range usedRange = Worksheet.UsedRange;
 usedRange.Interior.Color =    
 System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

  FormatCondition format = (FormatCondition)(Worksheet.get_Range("A1:D13",
            Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression,    
  XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
            "=$A1=$D1", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
  Type.Missing));

   format.Font.Bold = true;
   format.Interior.Color = 
   System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);//Duplicate values
```

Hope this helps ..it worked for me

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already checked the link you provide and it doesn't work for me (it throws COM exception). The solution you provided is very useful, but it doesn't solve my problem. I still don't know how to highlight duplicate values in range A1:A10.

Comment: It throws here: "var xlFC = xlS.FormatConditions[xlS.FormatConditions.Count];
"

Comment: I tried to cast: var xlFC = (Excel.FormatCondition)xlS.FormatConditions[xlS.FormatConditions.Count]; Also tried to declare Excel.FormatCondition instead of var.. but it throws COM exception.

Comment: Please refer to the code snippet I have written. ("A1:D13") is the excel range of my sheet so make sure that you are passing the right range from your sheet.It paints the range completely yellow ,it chooses the unique value and paints it red.

Comment: Thanks for you time. But i need to paint duplicated values not unique

Comment: I have no idea why was my question closed?

Comment: What if it's just one column I am checking for? After it is done, how do I save it to the file?